# What is the best way to transfer all my Visual Studio projects to svn?

Tags: visual-studio, svn, tortoisesvn, ankhsvn

Until now there is a disk folder named DEVELOPMENT.

This folder includes a top level folder named _LIB where the common libraries and layers (DAL projects, Business Layer projects e.t.c) are included.

There is also a RESOURCES folder where i have some common bitmaps that i use (mostly).

Aside to this _LIB folder there are folders that resemble the various domains of our business.

The domain projects follow the reference _LIB projects than reference the compiled dlls.

I need to transfer them under svn responsibility.

I would like to start with VisualSVN server,Ankhsvn and TortoiseSVN. All of them are installed and i have been playing with them for a little bit, but i am confused as to the overall strategy of this move.

From what i have understood i need to have clear picture for the following aspects (which i dont have and i need help):

-What to exclude and what to include.
-How to deal with the external project references.
e.t.c

**Additional Info:**

***After reading some more i came up to this and i need your comments:***

Steps:

- First create the repo and import anything i want there from TortoiseSVN. This will ensure that only the ignore list of tortoise will be active allowing me to import to repo nearly everything.
- For every day use INSIDE a project i will use AnkhSVN. It will keep my solution clean from bin,obj and the other SCC API files that i dont need.

-For anything outside VS i will use TortoiseSVN.

Comment: Added some more info after some reading and tests.

Comment: If the SVN plug-in that connects the IDE to SVN is doing it's job, the IDE will be the adding things to SVN via the plug-in, but it (the IDE) will decided what things need to be added and it will only add files that need to be there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In our projects we use ["stantdard-structure"](http://blogs.collab.net/subversion/subversion_repo) with `trunk`, `branches` and `tags`. Works fine and new teammember who formally worked with svn understand the structure and "the way to use" quickly.

All "main-projects" (your domains?) have this structure. We also have some lib-folders (like you) which have there on place on server (at the moment without `trunk`, ...). Every teammember have to check out the lib folder and the `trunk` or `branches` he need for his work.

If you use Tortoise or ankhsvn to commit your changes is often a matter of taste.

Hope this helps you a little bit to "unconfuse" you. Please feel free for further enquiry.

Comment: So, i have to transfer my present directory structure on my laptop disk to folders in repository? should i create an empty repository from tortoisesvn and then add the existing directories? When that happens i want to be sure that i do not exclude things i want..because after i will delete my local folders and rely only on svn..This is the confusing part.

Comment: To first question: what I can assume form here: yes.
To second question: this is what I also would do.
As far as I know you have not to delete anything if you use SVN-Import (context menu of Tortoise on a non-svn-folder)

Comment: After reading your comments and reading on the net i will update my question on what i think its right and please update your answer if is needed and comment.

Comment: @e4rthdog: From my point of view your "planed steps" are a good basic to start.

Comment: One last question. I use these steps and now i need to svn del all .net dependant files from the repository. I can t seem to find out how, except of course by deleting one by one the directories from repository.

Comment: @e4rthdog: Best Way is to do a clean up in VS *before* import to svn. If the files are still in repo I would recommend to do two checkouts. In one of them open VS an make a clean up, then make a file/directory-based compare of the two checkouts.

Comment: Good idea..IF you want contribute here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22532861/how-to-batch-delete-files-directories-from-svn-repository

Comment: I post my enlarged comment to your question as answer. Thanks for the tip. Gave you +1 there. Thanks for accepting (another +1 for that).